# How to disable specific value in foreach blade laravel on the table

Tags: laravel-5.3, laravel-blade

Help me guys, for this picture i want to disable view specific data from blade laravel this is the picture

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CuwB9.jpg 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/NQfIc.jpg

this is my blade laravel file

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-responsive" style="margin-top: 20px">
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>NO</th>
     <th>NAMA</th>
     <th>JABATAN</th>
     <th>PROJECT</th>
     <th>POSISI DALAM PROJECT</th>
     <th>START PROJECT</th>
     <th>FINISH PROJECT</th>
     <th>DAYS PROJECT</th>     
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>

   @php
    $no = 1;
   @endphp

   @foreach ($data as $value)

    <tr>     
     <td>{{ $no ++ }}</td>     
     <td>{{ $value->EMPLOYEE_NAME }}</td>
     <td>{{ $value->EMPLOYEE_TITLE }}</td>
     <td>{{ $value->PROJECT_NAME }}</td>
     <td>{{ $value->PROJECT_ROLE }}</td>
     <td>{{ $value->PROJECT_START }}</td>
     <td>{{ $value->PROJECT_END }}</td>
     <td>{{ $value->PROJECT_DURATION }}</td>
    </tr>
    
   @endforeach 
   </tbody>
  </table>
```

and then controller to view $data

```js
 public function index(){
     $data['data'] = DB::table('project')->join('employee','project.EMPLOYEE_ID','=','employee.EMPLOYEE_ID')
                                            ->select('EMPLOYEE_NAME' , 'EMPLOYEE_TITLE' , 'PROJECT_NAME' , 'PROJECT_ROLE' ,'PROJECT_START' , 'PROJECT_END' , 'PROJECT_DURATION')
->get();

    return view('index',$data);
}
```

Help me guys... .

Comment: Please read this: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest

Comment: Do you want to disable information based on which condition?

Comment: I do not understand when taking data using foreach and in it there are conditions. I've tried it, but the result still fails.Can you make the condition? According to the above case.